# Javascript obfuscator which reuses variable names to make search and replace ineffective

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, replace, naming-conventions

I'm wondering if any of the many JavaScript obfuscators go out of their way to make reverse engineering difficult by specifically trying to reuse variable names as much as possible where scoping rules mean they will not conflict.

Obviously good IDEs with refactoring support which enables contex- or language-sensitive variable renaming would not be fooled by this (unless they are buggy).

But such a feature could certainly slow down and complicate casual reverse engineering for people using plain search and replace features of text editors to rename variables while attempting to understand code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jscompress.com/ does exactly that.

Comment: Yes it does do it. It doesn't seem to document that it does and it doesn't have any options to allow things like also renaming global variables and functions... but it certainly answers my question as I asked it. (-: